Copy file from S3 to S3 using Glue with Streaming
I want to copy a file from source s3 bucket to target S3 using Glue Job(Python script)

A file in source s3 in compressed format(zip or tar) then decompress it and upload it to target s3
A file in source s3 already in de-compressed format then upload as it to target s3.

I am able to meet the requirement with putobject and its working fine. But I think putobject may cause issue when the files are big. So looking for alternative approaches - multipart upload or upload_fileobj.
I am facing "Fileobj must implement read" error when I try with multipart upload and upload_fileobj
I am facing "Fileobj must implement read" error when I try with multipart upload and upload_fileobj
